# Send data from textbox with ajax to asp.net mvc 5 controller

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I need some help. I write little app using ASP.NET MVC5 with JavaScript, jQuery, Ajax... and I can't send data from javascript to MVC Controller and change the model.

**ViewModel**

```
public class MyViewModel
{
//...
    public string SearchString { get; set; }
    public int? FirstInt { get; set; }
    public int? SecondInt { get; set; }
}
```

**Javascript**

```
    function keystroke() {
        var a = 0, b = 0;
        $('#search').keyup(function (event) { a = 1; });

        $('#search').keydown(function (event) { b = 1; });

        $("#search").keypress(function (event) {
            if (e.which === 13) {
                e.preventDefault();
                $('form').click(function () {
                    sendForm(a, b);
                });
            }
        });
    };
    function sendForm(a, b) {
        $.ajax({
            url: @Url.Action("Index", "Home"),
            type: 'POST',
            contentType: 'application/json',
            data: JSON.stringify({
                FirstInt: a,
                SecondInt: b
            }),
            success: function () {
                alert('success');
            }
        });
    };
```

**View**

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "Home", FormMethod.Post, new { @class = "form-inline", role = "form" }))
            {
                <div class="form-group has-feedback">
                    @Html.TextBox("SearchString", ViewBag.SearchFilter as string, new
            {
                @class = "form-control",
                onclick="keystroke()",
                id = "search"
            })
                </div>
            }
```

**Controller**

```
public async Task<ActionResult> Index(MyViewModel model)
        {
            //...
            if (model.SearchString != null)
            {
                //...
                var a = model.FirstInt;
                var b = model.SecondInt;
            }
            //...
            return View(model);
        }
```

Help me, please, to send all the values to controller. Those that changed in JavaScript and what I enter in the textbox. Thanks.

Comment: url: @Url.Action("Index", "Home") ?? it is not an url

Comment: I try write url: "Home/Index" but it does not work too

Comment: Is it hit brake point when you send request in debug mode?

Comment: Html.BeginForm("Index", "Home", FormMethod.Post... this post works without HttpPost attribute, but I do not get the value from javascript, that's the problem. When I use brakepoint after the var b = model.SecondInt;, a and b are null

Comment: HttpPost  is restriction to "listen" to post requests only, without that attribute the method "listening" for both GET and POST. 

Do you have "name" attribute in your HTML controls?

Comment: a and b variable are only exist in javascript side. FormMethod.Post sends model data and this one will not include manipulated data from javascript side. You have to take either ajax post or FormMethod.Post.

Comment: ok, how to take only ajax post?

Comment: can you write how to remove FormMethod.Post and send data use only ajax post? please @genichm

Comment: Remove using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "Home", FormMethod.Post, new { class = "form-inline", role = "form" })) and opening + closing brackets "{" "}" it will remove form from your page. This is the simplest way but you will need to create all fields by yourself. In addition your function do this $("#search").keypress(function (event) you using event variable and then (e.which when e does not exists, use event.which

Comment: You have conflict because you try to send data when user presses on enter while field inside of form is in focus, it makes submit to the form.

Comment: Please write the complete solution as it should look completely @genichm

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Javascript Code:

```
function keystroke() {
var a = 0, b = 0;
    $('#search').keyup(function (event) { a = 1; });

    $('#search').keydown(function (event) { b = 1; });

    $("#search").keypress(function (event) {
        if (e.which === 13) {
            e.preventDefault();
            $('form').click(function () {
                var text = $("#search").val()
                sendForm(a, b, text);
                return false;
            });
        }
    });

};
function sendForm(a, b, text) {
    var data = {FirstInt: a,SecondInt: b,SearchString: text}
    $.ajax({
        url: 'Home/Index',
        type: 'POST',
        contentType: 'application/json',
        data: data,
        success: function () {
            alert('success');
        }
    });
};
```

Controller Code

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<ActionResult> Index(MyViewModel model)
    {
        //...
        if (model.SearchString != null)
        {
            //...
            var a = model.FirstInt;
            var b = model.SecondInt;
        }
        //...
        return View(model);
    }
```

Comment: When I write some text in textbox and press enter key, SearchString get the value, but a and b are null

Comment: Plz, show me How do I change the view to only send ajax post?

Comment: does $("#search").keypress execute?

Comment: yes I tried, but most likely you're right and ajax post and FormMethod.Post in conflict

Comment: yes, $("#search").keypress works, I checked through the alert("keypress works");

Comment: add return false; at the end of $("#search").keypress

Comment: added, but its did not help

Comment: plz, can you write how to remove FormMethod.Post and send data use only ajax post?

Comment: <input type="text" name="fname" class="form-group has-feedback" id="search">
Put this code into your .cshtml file

Comment: Well actually nothing has changed @gypsyCoder