# Submit data from textbox to asp net mvc controller using ajax

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I have this

**View**

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "Home", FormMethod.Post, new { @class = "form-inline", role = "form" }))
    {
        @Html.TextBox("SearchString", ViewBag.SearchFilter as string, new { @class = "form-control", onclick="keystroke()", id = "search" })
    }
```

**Controller**

```
//GET: Home
public async Task<ActionResult> Index(MyViewModel model)
            {
                //...
                if (model.SearchString != null)
                {
                    //...
                    var myString = model.SearchString;
                    var b = model.FirstInt
                }
                //...
                return View(model);
            }
```

**ViewModel**

```
public class MyViewModel
{
//...
    public string SearchString { get; set; }
    public int? FirstInt { get; set; }
}
```

**Javascript**

```
function keystroke() {
        var firstint = 1;
        $("#search").keypress(function(event) {
            if (event.which === 13) {
                event.preventDefault();
                $("form").submit(function() {
                    var text = $('#SearchString').val();
                    sendForm(firstint, text);
                });
            }
        });
    }
function sendForm(firstint, text) {
            var data = {FirstInt: firstint, SearchString: text}
            $.ajax({
                url: "Home/Index",
                type: 'POST',
                data: data,
                success: function () {
                    alert('success');
                }
            });
        };
```

and its does not work.

I want to when user press the Enter key in search-input, I sent to controller the text which he entered, and the value of firstint. If I remove all javasript, then pressing Enter all normally sends to the controller but I need the firstint value too.

Comment: What data does the controller receive?  I assume that in the `Index` code you can log the contents of `model`.

Comment: The user enters a string in the input field. I'm sending a string to the controller and some number. This number is calculated when user press a key. How can I do that? Watch this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30459261/send-data-from-textbox-with-ajax-to-asp-net-mvc-5-controller @HewWolff

Comment: You can also try @Ajax.BeginForm and declare you js functions

Comment: can you please write a working solution? @SHammelburg

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An example of using Ajax.BeginForm, you will need to reference

> jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js

otherwise it'll be like regular Html.BeginForm.

View:

```
@using (Ajax.BeginForm("Index", "Home", 
    new AjaxOptions { HttpMethod = "Post", OnFailure = "OnFailure", OnSuccess = "OnSuccess" }))
{
    <input type="text" name="Id" />
    // Your HTML inside  your form...
    <button type="submit">Submit Form</button>
}
```

Controller:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Index(FormCollection collection)
{
    var Id = collection["Id"];
    return View();
}
```

Javascript:

```
<script>
    function OnFailure(x, s, e) {
        alert(e);
        // More code here...
    }
    function OnSuccess(d) {
        alert(d);
        // More code here...
    }
</script>
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 3):

When you try to execute, the keypress event doesn't find firstint because it doesn't exists outside the function keystroke. So you have to declare it outside in the "global" variables (visible to all functions) and then you can use it inside the keypress event. Your code should like this:

```
var firstint;

$("#search").keypress(function(event) {            
        if (event.which === 13) {
            event.preventDefault();                
        }
    });

$("form").submit(function() {
          var text = $('#SearchString').val();
          sendForm(text);
    });

function keystroke() {
    firstint = 1;        
    $("form").submit();
}

function sendForm(text) {
        var data = {FirstInt: firstint, SearchString: text}
        $.ajax({
            url: "Home/Index",
            type: 'POST',
            data: data,
            success: function () {
                alert('success');
            }
        });
 };
```

Comment: I call keystroke() when user click to input and it it becomes in focus, whatch my code in html helper... new { @class = "form-control", onclick="keystroke()", id = "search" }

Comment: keypress doesnt work in #search and I dont know why... @Pipe2290